# closed fd with subprocesses, IPC, SMP

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipc

Given the function

```
def get_files_from_sha(sha, files):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import tarfile
    if 0 == len(files):
        return {}
    p = Popen(["git", "archive", sha], bufsize=10240, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=p.stdout, mode='r|')
    p.communicate()
    contents = {}
    doall = files == '*'
    if not doall:
        files = set(files)
    for entry in tar:
        if (isinstance(files, set) and entry.name in files) or doall:
            tf = tar.extractfile(entry)
            contents[entry.name] = tf.read()
            if not doall:
                files.discard(entry.name)

    if not doall:
        for fname in files:
            contents[fname] = None
    tar.close()
    return contents
```

which is called in a loop for some values of `sha`, after a while (in my case, 4 iterations) it starts to fail at the call to `tf.read()`, with the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../yap-analysis/extract.py", line 243, in <module>
    commits, identities, identities_by_name, identities_by_email, identities_freq = build_commits(commits)
  File "../yap-analysis/extract.py", line 186, in build_commits
    commit = get_commit(commit)
  File "../yap-analysis/extract.py", line 84, in get_commit
    contents = get_files_from_sha(commit['sha'], files)
  File "../yap-analysis/extract.py", line 42, in get_files_from_sha
    contents[entry.name] = tf.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 817, in read
    buf += self.fileobj.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 737, in read
    return self.readnormal(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 746, in readnormal
    return self.fileobj.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 573, in read
    buf = self._read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 581, in _read
    return self.__read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 606, in __read
    buf = self.fileobj.read(self.bufsize)


ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I suspect there is some parallelization that subprocess attempts to make (?).

What is the actual cause and how to solve it in a clean and robust way on python2?

Comment: You can change `if (isinstance(files, set) and entry.name in files) or doall` to `if doall or entry.name in files:` and save yourself a type test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `.communicate()` on the `Popen` instance; it'll read the `stdout` stream until it is finished. From the documentation:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.

The code for `.communicate()` even adds an explicit `.close()` call on the `stdout` of the pipe.

Simply removing the call to `.communicate()` should be enough, but do also add a `.wait()` *after* reading the tarfile contents:

```
tar.close()
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

It could be that `tar.close()` also closes `p.stdout`, but an extra `.close()` there should not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the `p.communicate()`.  This method sends to stdin, reads from stdout and stderr (which you are not capturing) and waits for the process to terminate.

`tarfile` is trying to read from the processes stdout, and by the time it does then the process is finished, hence the error.

I have not tried running your code (I don't have access to `git`) but you probably don't want the `p.communicate` at all, try commenting it out.